# java share data between thread

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, client

i have a java process that reads data from a socket server. Thus i have a `BufferedReader` and a `PrintWriter` object corresponding to that socket.

Now in the same java process i have a multithreaded java server that accepts client connections. I want to achieve a functionality where all these clients that i accept can read data from the `BufferedReader` object that i mentioned above.(so that they can multiplex the data)

**How do i make these individual client threads read the data from BuffereReader single object?** Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I'm assuming you're saying that all the threads should get all the data, not just that whoever reads first should get a particular piece of data?

Comment: ya all of them should get data this is presently coming from the BufferedReader stream..

Comment: @ayush: I don't think you understood johusman's question - are you trying to *split* the data between the different clients, or should the *all* see *all* of the data? If the data is 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, should each client see 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 or might one client see 0, 1, 3 and the other see 2, 4?

Comment: @ayush, but do you see the distinction @johusman is making?  Does every thread need to read all the data?  Or do you want each thread only to get certain, disjoint chunks.

Comment: i want all thread to read the same data..that being the last thing read from the socket using `BufferedReader`...

Comment: @ayush: So only the *last* item? that's different again...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would strongly suggest that they *don't* access the `BufferedReader` directly. Assuming you know the format of the data, and that each client is trying to read the same format (if that's not the case, I can't see how it could work at all) I would suggest creating one thread to read from the `BufferedReader` and put work items in a `Queue`. There are *lots* of example of using producer/consumer queues in Java, and this is also likely to make it easier to test the client code.

Having only one thread accessing the `BufferedReader` means you don't need to worry about defining an atomic operation that all other threads will have to content for - your reading thread effectively defines that operation by deciding to add a work item to the queue.

EDIT: If all the clients should see *all* of the data, that reinforces my suggestion of having a single reader even further - except instead of having a `Queue` of data which items are removed from, you'd have a collection which clients can read *all* the existing data from. You'll need to use an appropriately thread-safe collection, but there are plenty of those in Java.

EDIT: Having just read your comment which says that each client should just see the last item read from the reader, that makes it even easier. Have one thread reading the data, but just keep a single variable with a reference to "the last item read". You probably either want to synchronize access to it or use an `AtomicReference`, but both of those are easy.

Comment: so if i want all threads to read all the data then what should i do? have a file where this data is written and then have synchronized access to this file by all clients.. ?or some other approach?

Comment: @ayush: All the data, or just the last item? You're contradicting yourself. Anyway, my "edit" paragraphs cover both possibilities - a single thread reading the data, but making it available either via an AtomicReference or a thread-safe collection.

Comment: thanks for the explanation..the data would keep coming continuously in `BufferedReader` and i want that all threads to read that data(the last one)..missing some data is acceptable..but all threads should get the same data...

Comment: @ayush you can make it so that the same "last" data is *available* to all readers at the same time, but you can't guarantee that they will all *actually read it* before "last" is updated next.  Some may, some may not, and in this case different readers may see a different sequence.  The only way to guarantee they see the same sequence is to make them all read *everything*.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing is probably to create a temporary file and use `java.nio.channels.FileChannel`.  The reason is that this already provides the reader/writer semantics you want.  An alternative is to re-implement these semantics yourself with an in-memory scheme.

What you would do is read from your reader and append to the end of the file.  Then your readers would get file channels initially pointing to the end of the file.  You'll have to be careful to make sure they don't think they have reached end of stream when you are simply waiting on more input from the reader.  You can either make downstream logic aware of this or provide some kind of wrapper around the readers.

Edit:  this was written with the understanding that you want all readers to see everything.  This is too complicated if that's not in fact what you want.

Answer (score 1):

In case you can't hold all the data in memory, you can use something like this:
(Uses a classic observer pattern where one thread monitors the source and the others are notified of the new data)

```
class Broadcaster {
    private final ConcurrentSkipListSet<Listener> listeners =
         new ConcurrentSkipListSet<Listener>();

    private final BufferedReader source = //inject source

    // register / de-gegister code
    public void register(Listener listener);
    public void deRegister(Listener listener);
    // usually it's used like broadcaster.register(this);

    public void broadcast(){
        String read = null;
        while((read = source.readLine())!=null){
            for(Listener listener : listeners){
                listener.send(read);
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

and

```
class Listener implements Runnable {
    private final Queue<String> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>();

    public void send(String read){
        queue.add(read);
    }

    public void run(){
        while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
            String got = queue.get();
            System.out.println(got);
        }
    }
}
```

I didn't test this thing or anything, so have mercy if it doesn't work!

**EDIT**: If you have memory constraint, you might want to do this as well:

```
Queue<String> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>(2000);
```

This will put a upper limit on how many elements can queue up in the queue, and when this limit is reached, threads that want to put elements on it will have to wait (if `add` is used, that is). This way the Broadcaster will block (wait) when the listeners can't consume the data fast enough (while in this simple scheme other listener could starve).

**EDIT2:** When you do this, you should preferably put only immutable things on the Queue. If you put for example `byte[]`, a impolite listener may change the data and the other threads may be surprised. If this is somehow impossible, you should put a different copy on each queue, e.g. `byteArray.clone()`. This may incur some performance hit though.