# How to create a simultaneous connection between a server and a client on the same network in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, networking

I am trying to create a MapleStory type game for my computer science final. It's basically a 2D RPG played over LAN. My question is how would I get the connection between two computers to be simultaneous?

```
    class MagicServer extends Thread
    {
       private ServerSocket serverSocket;

       public MagicServer(int port) throws IOException
       {
          serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
          //serverSocket.setSoTimeout(10000);
       }

       public void run()
       {
          Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
          while(true)
          {
             try
             {
                System.out.println("Waiting for client on port " + serverSocket.getLocalPort() + "...");
                Socket server = serverSocket.accept();

                System.out.println("Just connected to " + server.getRemoteSocketAddress());

                DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(server.getInputStream());
                DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());

                System.out.println(in.readUTF());

                for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
                {
                    System.out.println(in.readUTF());
                    out.writeUTF(kb.nextLine());
                }

                server.close();

             }

             catch(SocketTimeoutException s)
             {
                System.out.println("Socket timed out!");
                break;
             }

             catch(IOException e)
             {
                e.printStackTrace();
                break;
             }
          }
       }
       public static void main(String [] args)
       {
          int port = 2001;
          try
          {
             Thread t = new MagicServer(port);
             t.start();
          }catch(IOException e)
          {
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
       }
    }
```

I was experimenting with this and I can only send/recieve messages between two computers in order (i.e. server sends to client then client sends to server) and I cannot go out of order. How would I do this?

Comment: If your asking to have to computers literally send data to each other simultaneously, I don't think it is possible. in the world of networking, computers don't communicate at the same time. They send a signal then wait for a response.

Comment: It's not only possible, but quite common.

Answer (score 0):

You have to de-couple your reads/writes by using multiple threads or through interlocked queues to manage your work.

In you loop, you force the serialization by doing a read then a write in the code.

There's no reason you couldn't spawn a reader thread that feeds into a queue to perform work by worker threads and writes happen on another thread.  You just need to have synchronization on the work queues.

You can also poll the socket to see if there's any data available to read and if not, send any data waiting to be written.

There's more exotic ways to do it, and plenty of examples, search around and see what your comfortable with.

There's a similar thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5190895/java-share-data-between-thread)

Answer (score -2):

You could use multiple threads to have a connection one way in one thread on one port and a connection the other way on a different port in the other thread.  This could introduce some synchronization issues though, so I would recommend rethinking your design so that communication only needs to occur in one direction at a time (you can switch back and forth as often as you like if need be).

Comment: TCP is bidirectional. The second connection is completely unnecessary.